# I am trying to verify a sufficiency condition for one concave function being greater than another

Tags: functions

Let $f,g:[a;b]\rightarrow R$ be two functions that are strictly concave and strictly increasing on $(a;b)$. Moreover, $f(a)>g(a)$ and $f(b)>g(b)$.
Finally, let $x\in(a;b)$ such that $g'(x)=\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}$ (unique existence is no problem due to MWT and other conditions).

Is it sufficient for $f>g$ on the whole interval $[a;b]$ if $f(x)>g(x)$?
Plz provide sketch of proof or counterexample..

Many thx in advance

Chris

Comment: Could you explain this phrase: "Is it sufficient for f>g on the whole interval [a;b] if f(x)>g(x)?"

Comment: Do you mean "MVT" (mean value theorem) instead of "MWT"?

Comment: As a hint, you might consider $g(y)=\sqrt{y}$ over $y \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Yeah of course is the function f greater than the function g for all elements of the interval (a;b) if for x as determined above the inequality f(x)>g(x) holds...Also you can asume that f,g are of course sufficiently regular

Comment: @ Michael: Your first question, yes : Mean Value Theorem, sorry.. Your hint I dont get

Comment: The hint is to work towards a counterexample.  Build a linear $f$, then bend it.

Comment: No, if I build a linear f that is above g and start bending it such that it becomes concave, then it remains above g

Comment: I don't get your last comment.  Also, since you want a _counterexample_, your linear function $f$ should _not_ be above $g$ always. In other words, to make life easy, first remove the restriction that $f$ is strictly concave.

Comment: Oh sorry, I dont WANT a counterexample. I would like to prove the statement as it is phrased above actually and my intuition says, it should hold but Im not sure.

Comment: You can decide whether you want to work for a very long time trying to prove it, or to work for a very short time to get a counterexample. =)

Comment: Yeah but if the statement is true, there wont be counterexamples ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(t) = 0.24+t^{1/2}$ and $g(t) = t^{\frac{1}{4}}$ on $[0,1]$.

$x = 4^{-\frac{4}{3}} \sim 0.157$.

A matlab plot will show that $f$ is not always above $g$.

Comment: Your f function is convex though and I assumed that it is concave

Comment: There was a mistake in latex typing. corrected now.

Comment: Ok, still not it!! Because g(x)~0.63 and f(x)~ 0.5 which violates my last condition f(x)>g(x)!

Comment: Just build your own example from my comments above: grab any two points on the $g$ curve that come before $x$ and draw a line thru them!

Comment: Yap ok now I get it, thx michael

Comment: Sorry the constant should be 0.24. I corrected it. But the idea is there.